# How to check if elements from each list in a column of liste are all the same?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pd.dataframe where one column has lists,  I need to create a new column that return true if all elements are equal or false if they are not

| col1 | col_lists |
| --- | --- |
| First | [a,b,d] |
| Second | [a,a] |

this will be the desired outcome:

| col1 | col_lists | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | [a,b,d] | False |
| Second | [a,a] | True |

Comment: So if you have something like `[a,a,b]` the output should be `False`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension,

```
df["new_col"] = [True if len(set(l)) == 1 else False for l in df["col_lists"]]
```

---

The long way,

```
new_col = []

for l in df["col_lists"]:
  if len(set(l)) == 1:
    new_col.append(True)
  else:
    new_col.append(False)

df["new_col"] = new_col
```

---

Converting a list to a set allows us to get all the unique values from that list. If the set of that list has more than one value, then that would mean that the list doesn't have a single value for all its positions. So in that case, we set the value for the new column as False. Otherwise, we set it as True.

Comment: `df["new_col"] = [True if len(set(l)) == 1 else False for l in df["col_lists"]] `  worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.assign(new_col = df['col_lists'].map(lambda x: len(set(x)) == 1))
```